# ListView with spinner missing item click

Tags: android

Hi I am new to android and I'm building my first app.I've implemented a listview which contains an ImageView a TextView and a Spinner(a drop down list).I populate the spinner with data dynamically,the thing is that every time that the spinner is empty the list behaves accordingly,though this doesn't happen if there is at least one item in the spinner.If the spinner is not empty the onListItemClick function for the list is never called as if i never clicked it.I fill the spinner on the getView function on my implementation of the adapter I use for the list,I don't know if it's relevant I mentioned it just in case.

Comment: Please be more clear/concise in your question...

Comment: i think i'm clear enough.I just wonder for what reason i cannot get the item click event whenever my spinner is not empty...

Comment: why was this question closed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually this one tricked me as well! i found out this [article](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3414) your listview won't get the on click item event if it includes items that can get focus...try adding this on your listview xml it worked for me

```
 android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```